# How do I get a Samsung SCX-4729fd multifunction printer/scanner working?

Tags: printing, samsung, scanner

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I bought samsung SCX-4729fd multifunction. Printer function is working well but what about scanning i have found a default installed program called simple scan but it didn't recognize the scanner.

I need configured that by command line.

Answer (score 0):

Install the common scan driver packages in Ubuntu. Then it will able to open with `simple-scan`.

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```